# GeoTIFF raster layer, c#

Tags: raster, c#, mapinfo, geotiff-tiff

We have a map rendering engine (renders from MapInfo Interchange Format). This engine uses Mercator Projection. Now we have to insert a raster layer (orthophotos of a city), we have GeoTIFF files with the .tfw files.

The idea: we create ~200x200px png files for each zoom level and the client will ask a WCF service for the images with parameters: zoom level, top left coordinate, bottom right coordinate.

My problem is: how to make the vector and raster layers work together? I don't really want to change the aspect ratio of the raster images.

Thanks in advance, Mart

Comment: Anyone around here play around with MapInfo?

Comment: Why does adding vectors into the equation cause problems, and how does that relate to the aspect ratio? Happy to help but not sure I understand the question entirely

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things with Mapinfo.

The first dataset that you add to a MapInfo session sets the projection of the workspace.  This an be overridden.

All subsequent layers added to the MapInfo session is reprojected on the fly to conform to the workspace projection.  This is done for convenience, but can be a problem when performing reprojects and exports of information.

Raster images are by default given a Zoom extent (the extents at which the raster will be displayed).  This can be overridden in the Layer Manager.  One of my major issues with MapInfo Professional when I first started using it was this.  I would add a raster dataset and it would not display.  It turned out to be this 'feature' - it is quiet smart when viewing large raster images.

Could you elaborate on aspect ratio?

Comment: Thank you, be we don't use MapInfo Prof or any other software. This is a custom software development.